# Coprime ideals and Dedekind zeta function over cyclotomic fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra-systems, cyclotomic-fields

For a positive integer $m$, the $m$-th cyclotomic ring is $R = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_m]$, the ring extension of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ obtained by adjoining an element $\zeta_m$ having multiplicative order $m$. The ring $R$ is contained in $m$-th cyclotomic number field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$, where $\zeta_m = e^{2\pi i / m}$.

Let $\mathcal{D}(R)$ be a discrete Gaussian distribution over $R$ of parameter $\sigma$. For $\ell \in [1,k]$ sample random ideals $g_1^\ell, g_2^\ell \gets \mathcal{D}(R)$. Define the lattices $\Lambda_1^\ell \overset{\Delta}{=} g_1^\ell \cdot R$ and $\Lambda_2^\ell \overset{\Delta}{=} g_2^\ell \cdot R$. For $i \in [1,r]$ sample random values, $g_2^\ell\xi_{1,i}^\ell \gets \mathcal{D}(\Lambda_2^\ell)$ and $g_1^\ell \xi_{2,i}^\ell \gets \mathcal{D}(\Lambda_1^\ell)$, where $r, k$ are positive integers. Consider the following term
$$
\sum_\ell \left(\sum_{i,j} v_{i,j} \xi_{1,i}^\ell \xi_{2,j}^\ell \right)g_2^\ell g_1^\ell,
$$
where $(v_{i,j})_{i,j} \in R^{r \times r}$.

For what value of $\ell$ is the above term well-spread over the ring $R$, i.e., lives in $R$ and not in the ideal $g_2g_1$? It feels to me that even for $\ell = 2$ the term would live in $R$, since 2 random elements are likely to be coprime. But I suppose this depends on the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(\ell)$ of the number field $K$.

- How can we compute $\zeta_K(\ell)$ over the cyclotomic number fields?
- How large $\ell$ needs to be to ensure that the probability of $\ell$
  elements not being coprime is negligible, i.e.,
  $1 - 1/\zeta_K(\ell) \approx 2^{-\kappa}$ (for some integer $\kappa \geq 128$)?

Comment: Hi! Since this is your first question, here is a heads up: while your question is pretty good overall, I would merely suggest that you lead the post with a question or some motivation of this problem before you jump into definitions and such since there is quite a lot to take in before one gets to know what you are asking for. Otherwise good question

Comment: Can you include a reference for discrete Gaussian distributions (on a lattice)?  And what does it mean to ‘’live” in $R$ but not in an ideal of $R$?

Comment: Does $\ell$ elements not being coprime mean that as an $\ell$-tuple they don’t generate the unit ideal, or is it a pairwise property? For $\ell>2$, there is a big difference even in $\mathbf Z$ between an $\ell$-tuple being pairwise coprime and being coprime as an $\ell$-tuple: $6, 10, 15$ is coprime as a triple but no two of them are coprime.

Comment: Last question: why should we expect for large $\ell$ that the probability of $\ell$ elements being pairwise coprime is equal to an integral power of $1/2$ instead of being, say,  irrational? Probably this is related to the use of a discrete Gaussian distribution, which I don’t know.

Comment: @KCd You can find more information about discrete Gaussian distribution here (Section 2.4): https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/293.pdf
By coprime I mean pairwise coprime. And lastly, I want to ensure that the term is well-spread over R, and does not come from some secret ideal $g_2g_1$, where by secret I mean unknown, since this has cryptographic applications.

Comment: @KCd And for the probability, for my case it is just important that the probability of $\ell$ elements not being pairwise coprime is negligible, let’s say something like $2^{-128}$.

Comment: I found the “definition” of a discrete Gaussian on a lattice coset $\Lambda + \mathbf c$ to be $\rho_s(\mathbf x)/\rho_s(\Lambda + \mathbf  c)$, where $\rho_s(\mathbf x) = \exp(-\pi \langle \mathbf x,\mathbf x\rangle/s^2)$. The denominator is not defined there. Is that just the sum of all $\rho_s$-values on $\Lambda + \mathbf c$?

Comment: Do you want that negligible probability to really equal $2^{-128}$ or rather be at most $2^{-128}$? If the latter, then in your post you should ask for a probability to be at most $1/2^\kappa$, not to be $1/2^\kappa$.

Comment: @KCd Yes, it is the sum. Maybe this definition is more clear for you: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/939.pdf#page11
As for the negligible probability, ideally equal to $2^{-128}$, but anything close to (and smaller than) it is fine.